# How to execute "source" command inside a shell script and then store the output of source in a variable within the shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, script, shell-script

I have written a shell script (called profile.sh) to fetch temperature values from the Android MPSoC. Separately, I have found a shell script that fetches the FPS of an app on the Android system as provided here: https://github.com/NasdaqGodzilla/GetFPS

To get the FPS I need to execute the shell script (get_fps.sh) as mentioned in  https://github.com/NasdaqGodzilla/GetFPS by using the following command:

> source get_fps.sh

However, I want to get the output of FPS by calling the get_fps.sh within my other shell script (profile.sh) and then store the output in a variable such that I can write it out to a csv file.

My shell script (profile.sh) is as follows:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
echo "power and temperature reading started...."

ini_signal="echo 1 > /data/local/tmp/signal.txt"
exec_signal=$(eval $ini_signal)

signal="cat /data/local/tmp/signal.txt"
exec_signal=$(eval $signal)

file_name=profile.csv
current_time=$(date "+%T")
new_fileName=$current_time.$file_name

while [[ $exec_signal != "0" ]]
do

TEMP_0="cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp"
TEMP_1="cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/temp"
TEMP_2="cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone2/temp"
TEMP0=$((OUT_TEMP0 / 100))
TEMP1=$((OUT_TEMP1 / 100))
TEMP2=$((OUT_TEMP2 / 100))
FPS=[GET THE OUTPUT OF source get_fps.sh]

echo $TEMP0,$TEMP1,$TEMP2,$FPS >> /data/local/tmp/$new_fileName

signal="cat /data/local/tmp/signal.txt"
exec_signal=$(eval $signal)
sleep 0.2

done
```

Comment: Why does that script need to be sourced instead of called normally? Did you try calling it normally and see if it still does what you need it to? I note your own script's shebang is asking for a Bourne shell, but the get_fps script's shebang asks for bash. Are you sure interpreting a bash script in the more restrictive Bourne shell context is even the right thing to do here?

Comment: @Spiff : Hi. Thank you for your reply on this. I usually don't write scripts but for this task I had to. When u say "try calling it normally" do you mean ./get_fps.sh within my shell script? But if I call ./get_fps.sh within my script, how can I store the output in a variable such that I can write it out to a csv as shown in my script. Sorry, if the question seems silly but I'm almost new to shell script programming. Any suggestions?

Comment: Scripts usually have two output streams: stdout (standard output) and stderr (error messages). To capture the stdout of any command (including calling a script) into a variable, you can do `MYVAR=$(somecommand)`. However, this executes the command (or script) in a subshell. If that get_fps script really needs to be sourced because it really needs access to your current shell's environment for some reason, then this might not be suitable. I doubt `MYVAR=$(source myscript.sh)` will work if the script your calling truly needs to be sourced, because the `$()` syntax creates a subshell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to run the script `get_fps.sh` from my `profile.sh` here's the following code:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
echo "power and temperature reading started...."

ini_signal="echo 1 > /data/local/tmp/signal.txt"
exec_signal=$(eval $ini_signal)

signal="cat /data/local/tmp/signal.txt"
exec_signal=$(eval $signal)

file_name=profile.csv
current_time=$(date "+%T")
new_fileName=$current_time.$file_name

while [[ $exec_signal != "0" ]]
do

TEMP_0="cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp"
TEMP_1="cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/temp"
TEMP_2="cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone2/temp"
TEMP0=$((OUT_TEMP0 / 100))
TEMP1=$((OUT_TEMP1 / 100))
TEMP2=$((OUT_TEMP2 / 100))
FPS=$(source get_fps.sh)

echo $TEMP0,$TEMP1,$TEMP2,$FPS >> /data/local/tmp/$new_fileName

signal="cat /data/local/tmp/signal.txt"
exec_signal=$(eval $signal)
sleep 0.2

done
```

Basically, I am running the `get_fps.sh` and storing the output value in a variable named FPS as follows:

`FPS=$(source get_fps.sh)`

Comment: @Peregrino69 It is the actual answer to my question. Thank you for your help.